# What are good data structures to group these features? and what algorithms can be used for inserting and retrieving?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a list of 50 subjects.
I also have a list of 1000 schools which will teach at least one or more of these subjects. 
Every time I search for a school I'm thinking of caching this school with the subjects it teaches. What would be a good way to save this data in most optimal way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use Hash Tables, using school for the keys, and subjects for the element. Hash table's operations of insert, delete and search can have a complexity that may vary depending on the way you handle extra collisions(many keys could be hashed in the same index) . But in your problem collisions are unavoidable( subjects are shared between many schools ) so for example,the use of open addressing with double hashing could reduce extra collisions but not the implicit collisions in your problem .If you want to implement it yourself, using a good hash function ( uniform distribution of the key over the index ) and a simple list for collisions, can make you achieve insertion in O(1), deletion(search for a subject and its deletion) in O(50) and search in O(50) at the worst case, which i think is good (and simple and fast to implement) for the problem. More on hash tables and how to implement it : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 0):

I would store this information within a HashMap. A HashMap stores key-value pairs, so you would be able to map each school to the subjects taught at the school.

Here's an example of what the code may look like implemented in java:

```
public class Main{

     public static void main(String[] args){

         //Creates a HashMap with a String as the key and String[] as the value.
         Map<String, String[]> schools = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

         //Name of the college 
         String college = "College";

         //Subjects offered at said college
         String[] subjects = {"Physics","Calculus","Algorithms"};

         //Stores the college and its subjects within the HashMap
         schools.put(college, subjects);

         //Search and print the given subjects any college stored in the map. 
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(schools.get("College")));

    }
}
```

This code will return:

```
[Physics, Calculus, Algorithms]
```